# Appending date to filename in windows batch

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, formatting, cmd

I'm trying to append yesterday's date to a zip file using winzip. 
But I've got trouble getting the correct date formatting.
I've found the script

```vb
@echo off

set yyyy=
set $tok=1-3
for /f "tokens=1 delims=.:/-, " %%u in ('date /t') do set $d1=%%u
if "%$d1:~0,1%" GTR "9" set $tok=2-4
for /f "tokens=%$tok% delims=.:/-, " %%u in ('date /t') do (
 for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=/-,()." %%x in ('echo.^|date') do (
    set %%x=%%u
    set %%y=%%v
    set %%z=%%w
    set $d1=
    set $tok=
 )
)

if "%yyyy%"=="" set yyyy=%yy%
if /I %yyyy% LSS 100 set /A yyyy=2000 + 1%yyyy% - 100

set CurDate=%mm%/%dd%/%yyyy%

set dayCnt=%1
if "%dayCnt%"=="" set dayCnt=1

REM Substract your days here
set /A dd=1%dd% - 100 - %dayCnt%
set /A mm=1%mm% - 100

:CHKDAY
if /I %dd% GTR 0 goto DONE
set /A mm=%mm% - 1
if /I %mm% GTR 0 goto ADJUSTDAY
set /A mm=12
set /A yyyy=%yyyy% - 1

:ADJUSTDAY
if %mm%==1 goto SET31
if %mm%==2 goto LEAPCHK
if %mm%==3 goto SET31
if %mm%==4 goto SET30
if %mm%==5 goto SET31
if %mm%==6 goto SET30
if %mm%==7 goto SET31
if %mm%==8 goto SET31
if %mm%==9 goto SET30
if %mm%==10 goto SET31
if %mm%==11 goto SET30
REM ** Month 12 falls through

:SET31
set /A dd=31 + %dd%
goto CHKDAY

:SET30
set /A dd=30 + %dd%
goto CHKDAY

:LEAPCHK
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 4
if not %tt%==0 goto SET28

set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 100
if not %tt%==0 goto SET29

set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 400
if %tt%==0 goto SET29

:SET28
set /A dd=28 + %dd%
goto CHKDAY

:SET29
set /A dd=29 + %dd%
goto CHKDAY

:DONE
if /I %mm% LSS 10 set mm=0%mm%
if /I %dd% LSS 10 set dd=0%dd%

echo Date %dayCnt% day(s) before %CurDate% is %dd%%mm%%yyyy%

pause
```

This script displays the year as `YYYY`, resulting in a output of `DDMMYYYY`, where do I amend in order to get `DDMMYY` instead? Or does anyone have a easier way of appending `DDMMYY` (1 day before current date) into a filename?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Batch file below add 1 day to current date and show it in the desired format:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for %%d in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set days[!i!]=%%d
)
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set /A dd=10%%a %% 100+1, mm=10%%b %% 100, yy=%%c %% 100, yyMOD4=yy %% 4
)
if %yyMOD4% equ 0 set days[2]=29
if %dd% gtr !days[%mm%]! (
   set /A dd=1, mm+=1
   if !mm! gtr 12 (
      set /A mm=1, yy+=1
   )
)
if %dd% lss 10 set dd=0%dd%
if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%
set tomorrow=%dd%%mm%%yy%
echo %tomorrow%
REM ren oldname.ext oldname-%tomorrow%.ext
```

This Batch file assume that `echo %date%` show the date in DD/MM/YYYY format. If not, a slightly modification is needed.

Comment: Thanks Aacini for the above code, tested on my PC with a %date% showing DAY DD/MM/YYYY format, assuming I need to edit the code for such date format, how do I go about it?

Comment: @overst33r: Just change `"tokens=1-3 delims=/"` by `"tokens=2-4 delims=/ "`. Note that there is a space after the slash.

Comment: Thanks @Aacini, it worked perfectly! A very thank you for the prompt reply!

Comment: @overst33r: May I ask you to upvote my answer and select it as Best Answer?